# My search script is finding address rows that it shouldn't

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search engine that searches addresses. It works as designed but I've run across an issue that I can't figure out a work around for.

Currently if I search for "23 Main St" and let's say Main street is in the 87232 zip code. This search will display every address that's on Main street because the street number I'm searching for has "23" with is also in the 87232 zip code.

I'm wondering if there is a way to program it to accept the space behind the "23 " and that would rule out the zip code? Or maybe you guys have a more thought out solution?

Here is my query code. It uses ajax live search:

```
if($_POST['query'] != '') {

    $pieces = explode(" ", $_POST['query']);
    $index = 0;
    $substring = "";

  while ($index < count($pieces))  {
     $substring .=" CONCAT(Name,Address,City,State,Zip) like '%" . $pieces[$index] . "%'"   ;

     if ($index !=count($pieces)-1){ 
         $substring .= " and "; 
     }

    $index++;
  }

$query = "SELECT * FROM database where ";
$query .=  $substring; 
$query .= ' ORDER BY Name ASC, dt DESC ';
}
```

Comment: Use a regular expression to match word boundaries instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: You should use `CONCAT_WS(' ',Name,Address,City,State,Zip)` so that the fields won't run into each other.

Comment: Sorry I had pasted an older version of my code. The most recent is now posted.

Comment: Barmer, That edit didn't stop the issue.

Comment: The main suggestion is to use a regular expression so you can match word boundaries with `[:<:]` and `[:>:]`